# Implementation of options_from_collection_for_select method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While working on `select` tag in rails, I am getting trouble with understanding `options_from_collection_for_select` method. From my understanding, this helper expects a collection of arbitrary objects and two additional arguments: the names of the methods to read the option value and text from, respectively:

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(Product.all, :id, :name) %>
```

This is good example to help understand the helper and is only valid if the `id` and `name` field belongs to `Product`. Suppose, in my case, I want `product.category.name` to be displayed as a text then how can I achieve this.

Again, the `product` and the `category` model has `one-to-one` association.

To achieve my goal, I tried following but I think, this association breaks the rule.

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(Product.all, :id, Product.category_name) %>
```

So, can someone suggest with the better solution?

Comment: paste your complete select tag what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have getter method for `category_name` in the `Product` model:

```
def category_name
    self.category.name
end
```

And in your view, you can simply call `:category_name`:

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(Product.all, :id, :category_name) %>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks @Madan now I know the issue, instead of defining the method for `category_name` I used scope. Can you suggest same using the scope. Thanks BTW

Answer (score 0):

You can use model method in this case.

In **product.rb**

```
def get_category_name
  self.category.name
end
```

and you can call it in options_from_collection_for_select as

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(Product.all, :id, :get_category_name) %>
```

First it will check whether any column exists in product table or not and then it will check for method.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an instance method with category_name in Product modal.

```
def category_name
  self.category.name
end
```

And, then use this helper in view.

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(Product.all, :id, :category_name) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Product model:

```
def category_name
  self.category.name
end
```

And in view:

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(Product.all, 'id', 'category_name') %>
```